openssl-genpkey: how do I specify the number of KDF rounds?
I'm generating a keypair with openssl and encrypting the private key as follows:
openssl genpkey -algorithm ED25519 -aes-128-cbc -pass stdin

Question: is there some way to specify the number of KDF rounds when using the command-line tools? Or is this not even possible for PEM output? I can't find anything in the docs. Ideally, I'd like something which is equivalent to ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a100. Thanks.
